# sfml-window-2.dll is missing [Visual Studio 2013]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sfml

I use visual studio express 2013, and so I downloaded the appropriate version of the SFML sdk (version 2.2, Visual C++ 12 (2013) - 32-bit). I followed the instructions provided on their site to the letter:

I specified the path of the include folder, the lib folder, and listed the additional dependencies.

I then added the dlls needed to the debug folder.

However, when I try to run the sample code that they have provided, I get an error stating that sfml-window-2.dll is missing. Obviously it clearly isn't since I placed it in the same folder where the exe is supposed to be (for some reason I can't find the .exe in the debug folder either).

Any help guys?

edit: Thanks for the help but I'd already placed the correct dlls in the debug folder. It simply did not work, for whatever reason.

However, using a youtuber's instructions, it managed to compile and run correctly. The only thing he did was specify the libraries and include files in the vc++ section of properties instead:

Here's the link for anyone else who may be confused: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTe7IVncH5E

Comment: Is it available from `%PATH`?

Comment: If your exe is not in the debug folder, then where is it? It's the first clue to an error in the configuration process. Then it says that `sfml-window-2.dll` is missing, not `sfml-window-2-d.dll` (with **-d**), which makes me think you're building in release mode but expect a debug exe.

Comment: I'm building in debug mode, but used the official instructions from the website. These instructions specify me to use the regular dlls and library instead of the debug ones.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I first started using SFML.

If you're running your application from your compiler, place the `sfml-window-2.dll` file in the same folder as your **project file**.

If you're running the application by itself, then you will need to place the `sfml-window-2.dll` file in the same folder as the application.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Link to tutorial which worked with my issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTe7IVncH5E

Main difference with this was starting going to VC++ instead of C++ in the properties area, and then when providing the dependencies in the input section for the linker, I switched over to debug and included the debug libraries, before switching to release and specifying the release versions.

Copy pasted all the dlls into the project folder and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to place all of the sfml-xxx-2.dll files in your debug folder in Visual Studio 2013 project folder:

- C:\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\projects\project name folder\debug... I hope this is clear...